# Sending sms with swift language in ios8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sms

I am trying to send an sms using MFMessagingComposeViewController

this is the code in swift :

after importing MessageUI

```
let msg:MFMessageComposeViewController=MFMessageComposeViewController()
msg.recipients=["7236446823423"]
msg.body="txt"
self.presentViewController(msg,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

i get an error :

libc++abi.dylib terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Did you include the framework file in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if MFMessageComposeViewController can send text `canSendText`:

```
if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText(){
            let msg:MFMessageComposeViewController=MFMessageComposeViewController()
            msg.recipients=["7236446823423"]
            msg.body="txt"
            self.presentViewController(msg,animated:true,completion:nil)
        }
        else {
            NSLog("your device do not support SMS....")
        }
```